# Função recursiva de números naturais está mostrando negativos

Tags: python, recursão

Preciso que de uma função recursiva (exercício) que imprima todos os [números naturais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_natural) entre A e B:

```
def cont(a, b):
if a < b:
    print(a)
    cont(a + 1, b)


cont(-3, 12)
```

O problema é que do jeito que fiz, estão sendo impressos os números negativos também.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Você tem duas condições distintas, uma é a condição do que deve ser impresso, e deve ser todos os números maiores ou iguais a zero, a outra condição é até quando deve continuar a recursão.

```
def cont(a, b):
    if a >= 0:
        print(a)
    if a < b:
        cont(a + 1, b)

cont(-3, 12)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sDeO3Q). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wcmnyrdh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/TwoParametersRecursion.py).

Tem como fazer uma função intermediária para evitar a recursão em itens desnecessários, ou seja, já começar do zero. Assim como faria de forma iterativa, o que alias é a melhor forma de fazer este tipo de algoritmo. Não gosto desses exercícios que forçam o uso de recursão.

E não há qualquer validação se o primeiro argumento é menor que o segundo, o que até deveria ser feito nessa função intermediária que eu disse.